# Using statement in Task

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, using

In an ASP.NET Web API controller I want to return an image. For streaming the image I need a `MemoryStream`. Normally I would wrap it in a `using` statement in order to make sure it gets properly disposed afterwards. However, as this executes asynchronously in a `Task` this doesn't work:

```
public class ImagesController : ApiController
{
    private HttpContent GetPngBitmap(Stream stream)
    {
        var pngBitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngBitmapEncoder.Save(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return new StreamContent(stream);
    }

    // GET api/images
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string id, string path)
    {            
        //do stuff           
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(); //as it's asynchronous we can't use a using statement here!
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = GetPngBitmap(stream)
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                return response;
            }
            //how can I dispose stream???
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `GetPngBitmap`, that is what matters in this case. When the 'png bitmap' has no reference to stream anymore, it's valid to dispose the stream.

Comment: call Dispose on stream after u call the `GetPnGBitmap()` method? Or use try finally block and call Dispose in finally, or call Dispose before u return the response. I don't see what the problem is? And why can't u use using?

Comment: Web API hosting layers take care of disposing the stream here once the response is written out and so you need not worry about closing the stream yourself...also what it the method call GetPngBitmap doing? Is it copying the content from a file to the memory stream? if yes, you need not create the memory stream again and just supply the file stream directly to Content as `StreamContent` instead..

Comment: @Caramiriel: I tried to dispose it but it didn't work.

Comment: @ShaktiPrakashSingh: because it's async it does not work

Comment: @KiranChalla: how does this work? MemoryStream is disposed by the Web API???

Comment: @Dunken: Could you please share how your GetPngBitmap method looks like so that i could give you a complete picture

Comment: @KiranChalla: I made it up for simplicity. It's basically: 
var pngBitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngBitmapEncoder.Save(stream);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StreamContent(stream)
};

Comment: Thanks for the code...yes, the stream would get closed by Web API's host layers, so you need not explicitly do anything from your side...Web API's hosting layers copies the content from your memory stream to network stream and then closes the source stream (your memory stream)...this is the same behavior in general for all responses..

Comment: What version of .NET/Visual Studio are you using? In .NET 4.5 and above you can use the `async\await` keywords to handle this. In Visual Studio 2012+ you can add `async/await` support to .NET 4.0 projects with the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: VS2010 and .net 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `MemoryStream` is one of the classes that implement `IDisposable`, because their base class does. `MemoryStream` doesn't hold any resources (apart from managed memory), so disposing it is actually unnecessary.
2. `HttpResponseMessage` is disposable. This means that when the whole response it sent, that object is disposed. Doing that disposes the contained `HttpContent`, which in the case of `StreamContent` disposes the underlying `Stream`. So even if you had a `Stream` that should be disposed, you don't have to worry about it in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this sounds naif, but can't you just dispose it at the end of the task?

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
//use the stream...
stream.Dispose();
```

edit: or "Close()", it's the same on MemoryStream.

Comment: No, I can't. If it would be possible I could use the using statement.

Comment: Sorry, just saw the return statement isinside

Answer (score -2):

use "using" then it will disposed automatically.

```
public class ImagesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/images
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string id, string path)
    {            
        //do stuff           
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           using( stream = new MemoryStream()) //as it's asynchronous we can't use a using statement here!
           {
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = GetPngBitmap(stream)
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                return response;
            }
            //how can I dispose stream???
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the comment after that line you modified? Why would this work?

Comment: because when you use "using" the .net will call .Dispose() to object after the "}". and if it exist before(return/exception) then it would happend anyway. you should read more about the "using" block and see what it does. google it

Comment: But the OP stated that *in this case* that "using" could not be used. Are you sure it *can* be used here? (I don't know either way, not enough experience with async)

Comment: maybe try another way to return a Photo? in my asp.net web api i returned an image in a different way

Answer (score -2):

Maybe return a `Tuple<HttpResponseMessage, Stream>` and attach a continuation task to dispose of the `Stream`?

```
public Task<Tuple<HttpResponseMessage,Stream>> Get(string id, string path)
{            
    //do stuff           
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = GetPngBitmap(stream)
            };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
            return Tuple.Create(response, stream);
        }
    })
    .ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Item2.Close());
}
```

Comment: 1. This won't compile, you're returning non-generic `Task`. 2. I really don't understand what is returning `Tuple` supposed to accomplish. 3. Does Web API know that when a `Tuple` is returned, it should access its `Item1`? I doubt that.

Comment: @svick, 1. The response was a suggestion which, 2. alongside the result, is supposed to return a reference to a `Stream` on which to call `Dispose()` **after** reading from the stream. 3. I do not know Web API and this brings me again to 1. - I offered a suggestion, not a solution. I do not know all the aspects of the project to make it a solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this. This will execute your initialRun first and after the async call, return in and it will execute the continue with.

```
        Task<System.IO.MemoryStream> initialRun = new Task<System.IO.MemoryStream>(() =>
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // use stream
            return stream;
        });
        initialRun.ContinueWith(new Action<Task<System.IO.MemoryStream>>((stream) =>
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        }), 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        initialRun.Start();
```

Comment: Maybe I miss the point but at the end I want to return a HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: @Dunken, you can create unlimited continuewith, trick it up to your liking, this one just demonstrates how you'd be able to dispose something after execution

Comment: I know, but basically I have to return an HttpResponse and then I want to dispose a stream... I don't see how to do this using a ContinueWith()